# Right-to-left support for localization placeholders when using "%@ %@"?

Tags: swift, swiftui, localization, foundation

I have a localization value where it's only 2 values. It would be something like:

```
English: "Example 5:04pm" 
Arabic: "5:04pm Example"
```

How would I accomplish this if the localization is `%@ %@`? This is what I'm doing:

```
en/Localizable.strings:
"some_key %@ %@" = "%@ %@";

ar/Localizable.strings:
"some_key %@ %@" = "%@ %@";

Swift:
let title = "Example"
let time = "5:04pm"
String(localized: "some_key \(title) \(time)"
```

However, this would always result in `Example 5:04pm` in both languages but I need them in a different order for some languages. I almost need something like this which isn't possible but just to illustrate:

```
en/Localizable.strings:
"some_key %@1 %@2" = "%@1 %@2";

ar/Localizable.strings:
"some_key %@1 %@2" = "%@2 %@1";
```

Notice how they are numbered so I can control the output. Is there a way to attach identifiers to the placeholder so I can order them differently depending on the right-to-left and other scenarios where nouns and verbs are semantically and sequentially different for different languages or any better way to achieve this?

Comment: Use `%1$@` & `%2$&`, see https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Comment: Thank you that worked! For reference, I had to do this: "some_key %@ %@" = "%2$@ %1$@"